# Duplicating Product Group Price

Tags: product, group-price

When duplicating a a product by calling $_product->duplicate() the group price does not get duplicated, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The `duplicateAction()` is in `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` which calls the `duplicate()` method of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`.

In the `duplicate()` method, the data is set on the new product.

There's an event which you can use to hook in, retrieve the group price of the current product and set it to the new product:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
 'catalog_model_product_duplicate',
  array('current_product' => $this, 'new_product' => $newProduct)
);
```